# Control + click operation is failing with winium driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, winium

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
element.click()
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`
```

I also tried control + 'a', control +'v' combinations, but its not working. Operation is successful in winium logs, but nothing changes in the GUI.

```
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
```